# Does setting a cookie with jquery.cookie and then testing for its existence confirm the browser accepts cookies?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, cross-browser

I'm confused about the best-pracice for checking if cookies are accepted by the browser.

Suppose you're using `JQuery` and, specifically, `jquery.cookie`, would the following work on all (modern) browsers? Particularly I wondering about browsers like IE 6.

```
$.cookie('test_name', '1');
if( $.cookie('test_name') == null ) { 
    console.log('cookies not accepted by browser');
else {
    console.log('good to go.');
    $.cookie('test_name', null);
}
```

It seems from other questions on SO that people are suggesting you have to set the cookie and then check it server-side on the next request, which differs from the above approach. So, does the above work on all (modern) browsers?

Comment: Why do you need to know whether cookies are supported?

Comment: @zzzzBov I'm not sure I see how that's pertinent to the question? Does the answer to your question make a difference to the above's correctness?

Comment: I can't see a reason why it wouldn't work. I would say that setting it client-side and checking server-side (or vice-versa) is a more complete test of functionality though.

Comment: It's better to check on the next request. That's when the browser sends the cookie headers if the cookies were actually set. It doesn't need to be done server side really. Your approach is fine, albeit, would be better if checked after a refresh.

Comment: side note: IE6 **is not** a modern browser

Comment: What does "browser accepts cookies" even mean? You're asking about modern browsers. Usually all modern browsers support cookies. It's just that the user might deny them at all, for a specific site, or even specific cookies etc. Probably after you have done the testing.

Comment: @Robert I think you answered your own question in your comment. As you so astutely posited, "browser accepts cookies" means the user has enabled the browser to accept cookies, or, put another way, not told it to reject cookies.

Comment: @Edwardr Oh, alright. So what I mean is that this isn't a true/false question. For example only your test cookie could be rejected while any other cookies might be allowed. But really those are special cases. Usually you would simply assume that cookies are accepted. But I think in the majority of cases the testing would do exactly what you are trying to achieve. It would just take some testing to confirm it. Server-side testing would even work if JS was disabled.